# How DLL references work?

Tags: .net, wpf, dll

So I have got a **WPF Controls Library** type project called **SweekUI** that I'm referencing in an **Outlook 2010 Add-in** type project. In the add-in project, if I try to create an instance of one of the Windows of SweetUIcall and call `ShowDialog()` on it, it would tell me that `ShowDialog()` is not a member of that window. Why? SweetUI already references all required WPF libraries and compiles correctly. When I add a reference of SweetUI in another project, it should be able to resolve it, no?

Comment: Because SweekUI references WPF DLLs then they must be referenced in your Outlook add-in too (remember your controls base class is WPF and C# compiler has to know everything about a class to use it).

Comment: @Adriano: but that info can already be resolved from SweetUI, no? In other words, SweetUI should be self-describing in the sense that it is referencing a few GAC libraries and it should be able to tell their names and addresses once another piece of code tries to resolve it.

Comment: no they must be **explicit**. You don't need to reference a DLL _used_ by a library you reference but you need to reference that DLL if it is  _involved in compilation_ (base class, inherited methods and so on). It's little bit annoying but it makes sense because you may reference a different version too. AFAIK it's not a .NET requirements but it's how C# compiler works (then it may be different for other compilers).